# Is there a way to save a matplotlib animation as a video (with ffmpeg) so that the last frame is held for N seconds?

Tags: matplotlib, animation, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMpegWriter to save a matplotlib animation as a video. I'd like to hold the last frame for some seconds at the end of the video.

As a workaround, one could modify the animation itself by repeating the last frame for a number of extra steps. This number of steps can be computed as a function of the desired "hold duration" and the interval/fps of the animation.

Nonetheless, I'd like to know if there's a cleaner way to do the same without artificially modifying the animation itself and using instead some extra arguments for the writer (which uses ffmpeg in my case). Unfortunately I don't know much of ffmpeg so I'd like to have some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. I ended up running a ffmpeg command (with `subprocess.run`) after saving the video with matplotlib:

```sh
ffmpeg \
   -i <your-input-file> \
   -vf tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=<your-stop-duration> \
   <your-output-file>
```

I've not tried if it's possible to pass this filter to `FFMpegWriter` directly.